# Phonegap plugin threading

Tags: javascript, multithreading, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

In the 3.2.0 documentation (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins) says:

> The plugin's JavaScript does not run in the main thread of the WebView interface; instead, it runs on the WebCore thread, as does the execute method.

The original event loop of Javascript browsers is single-threaded, which in fact eliminates all possible problems of race conditions.

1) What do they mean that 'The plugin's JavaScript does not run in the main thread of the WebView interface'?, this violates the default idea of single-threaded event loop?

2) If it runs in the same thread of the execute method, that means that .onSuccess() is synchronous?.

I'm more concerned about question 1), because I could have concurrency issues if two threads are executing JS on the same data. (They seem to call .runOnUiThread and create a new Runnable... two threads in the event loop?)